# statement.executeQuery() return wrong result

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I run SQL statement in mysql shell:

```
mysql> select amulet from nrotienkiem.player where id = 1;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| amulet                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{"id":213,"point":1686124182092},{"id":214,"point":0},{"id":215,"point":0},{"id":216,"point":0},{"id":217,"point":0},{"id":218,"point":0},{"id":219,"point":1686137387317},{"id":522,"point":0},{"id":761,"point":0},{"id":762,"point":0}] |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I run in Java, it replaces `,` with `«`:

```
root@NXT:/home/nxtpro# java -jar Test.jar
[{"id":213«"point":1686124182092}«{"id":214«"point":0}«{"id":215«"point":0}«{"id":216«"point":0}«{"id":217«"point":0}«{"id":218«"point":0}«{"id":219«"point":1686137387317}«{"id":522«"point":0}«{"id":761«"point":0}«{"id":762«"point":0}]
```

This is java code:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nrotienkiem", "root", "root");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `player` WHERE `account_id`=1;");
        if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("amulet"));
        }
    }
}
```

System information:

- Ubuntu Server 20.04
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.46, for linux-glibc2.12 (x86_64)
- Java 8
- mysql-connector-java 5.1.23

Comment: type of that colum is TEXT

Comment: MySQL Connector/J 5.1.23 is pretty old. I'd suggest trying with a newer version. The latest 5.1.x is 5.1.49, latest overall is 8.0.33.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe due to the presence of some Unicode characters in the string content in the MySQL database, and the system is not handling these characters correctly when outputting them, resulting in strange symbols appearing.

You can try converting the string to a Unicode code point sequence when outputting it, and then outputting it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nrotienkiem", "root", "root");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `player` WHERE `account_id`=1;");
        if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
            String amulet = rs.getString("amulet");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < amulet.length(); i++) {
                builder.append("\\u").append(Integer.toHexString(amulet.charAt(i) & 0xFFFF));
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried rs.getString("amulet").replace("«",","); and it's working, i wonder why it's return wrong result?

Comment: I guess it should be related to encoding, from the encoding used in the database to the encoding used in Java, and then to the default encoding of the operating system. You can check if everyone is using UTF-8. If they are all the same, I don't have any direction.

Comment: I agree with Ziv - this seems like an encoding issue.  In your MySQL shell run the command `status` and check your have a UTF-8 character set.  Then try `show create table player;` to check the table level